# Error when using SpreadsheetApp's addEditors function under a shared drive's spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

When I use the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addEditors()` on a spreadsheet inside a Shared Drive (this doens't occur if I move the spreadsheet to My Drive), it returns the following error for editor who are not already an editor:

> You do not have permissions to access the requested document.

I'm able to add editors as usual using the interface dialog, so I don't think it's not a privilege problem regarding adding editors. Maybe this is some bug because I'm not a member of the Shared Drive (I'm only editor of the spreadsheet)?
Did anyone experienced this same problem? Can I get around it, without moving the file to My Drive, or adding myself as a member of the entire Shared Drive (there are other documents which I'm not supposed to access)? Should I file a bug report to Google?

Comment: Is the user that is an editor of the sheet able to view the script from the `Tools > Script editor` menu item? Can you share the script directly with them from the Script editor's `File > Share` menu item?

Comment: i also have the same issue on shared drives (This only happens if the user that you want to add have the role 'content manager' in your team).